# multiple users remote access using ssh key based authentication

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, key-authentication

I'm new to Linux, I'm having CentOS 7. I want to allow multiple users for one server (Path - /var/www/ folder) using ssh key based authentication.
For that I have created 2 new users from my root account and created ssh key using `ssh-keygen` for the first user and transferred that to authorized keys file.

#### My question

Is when I create `ssh` key for 2nd user does the authorized keys file will get over written? If so how do I enable the `ssh` key for second user.

As per my knowledge, private key will be kept by the user and public key to be given to the rest. so in that case I need to generate `ssh` key from the user account and not from the root, then put that key in authorized keys file.

Comment: are you trying to add multiple users to same account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that you want multiple keys per account, then

Add one public key per line. In `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
To do this copy the keys to `~/.ssh`, then do `(cd ~/.ssh; cat *.pub > authorized_keys)`, alternatively you can add one key with `cat new_key.pub >> authorized_keys`.

However you probably don't want multiple users to share an account. It would be better to set up multiple accounts.